# Android send email causes Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android

I am try to create an app which sends emails along with some attachments. For this I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a/2033124#2033124) code. But I am getting error Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. How can I solve this any help please.

Comment: What's the full error? It should tell you what class you're missing.

Comment: Here is trace  
07-09 18:41:58.619: E/AndroidRuntime(917): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-09 18:41:58.619: E/AndroidRuntime(917): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.mymailsendingactivity.Mail
07-09 18:41:58.619: E/AndroidRuntime(917):  at com.example.mymailsendingactivity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
07-09 18:41:58.619: E/AndroidRuntime(917):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-09 18:41:58.619: E/AndroidRuntime(917):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)

Comment: Ok, and how about posting the code at and around line 14 of your MainActivity?

Comment: Here is line 14 
new Mail("FTP backup failed", mailBody).send();

Comment: "New Mail" That's it. You don't have a class Mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all Make sure the JAR files are set to exported

```
 Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export
```

After that try cleanup your project by right clinking on you project >>source>>Cleanup

hope this will help.